# prometheus inside docker not scraping node_exporter

Tags: docker, prometheus

I installed prometheus with docker using the official [guide](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/) on their page.
Now I also have [node_exporter](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/node-exporter/) working on the host. Yet prometheus doesn't seem to scrape metrics of it.

I run prometheus using:

`sudo docker run -d -p 9090:9090 -v /home/main/prometheus/config.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus`

```
  - job_name: node
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']
```

```
curl -i localhost:9100
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Length: 150
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html>
<head><title>Node Exporter</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Node Exporter</h1>
<p><a href="/metrics">Metrics</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

## Update

apparently, this is fixed using the "-net=host" flag when running on docker:
`sudo docker run  --net=host -d -p 9090:9090 -v /home/main/prometheus/config.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus`

Why are they not telling about this? Prometheus can't access anything outside its container without this flag?

Comment: Could you verify there's something at port 9100? netstat or even curl -i localhost:9100

Comment: this helped me thanks. Given that the docs have a machine running on host network not the Docker network in https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/node-exporter/ it does seem that when mentioning how to spin up with Docker that the network would be useful mention :)

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation, the examples assume that Prometheus and the node exporter are running on the same host. In your case, Prometheus is running on docker, which means that the node exporter is located outside of the container.

You should try to reach your target with the container name, an IP, or with `host.docker.internal` or similar.